# Wordpress: How to add additional folder for articles, besides draft and published/unpublished?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I automatically add articles as drafts to wordpress with script, moderator approves articles and publishes them or sends to some "storage" folder, so I to be able to train my machine learning algorithms on them. I've used to use folder "trash" for storing unapproved articles with

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 999 );
```

in wp-config.php but it does not seem to work, articles are getting deleted anyway. So I think I should  add additional category for articles besides "draft", "published", etc. I've read wordpress codex but it seems this topic isn't covered by it and googling yields nothing useful, only "101 wordpress tips" types of pages.

Another question, how to implement additional category in such way further updates won't break it? Or may be I'm just doing it all wrong?

Comment: Use a user with contributor role to save articles as drafts as that user can't publish articles, then use a user with publish privileges to publish the article

Comment: @SyedQarib The problem with this approach is pollution of drafts with "bad" articles. I don't delete them as they are needed for training my classifier, but I don't want to force moderator no navigate through all that garbage.

Comment: Why not use a custom post type ?

Comment: @SyedQarib it seems it is exactly the feature I need, thank you very much. If you will write more detailed answer as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom post type will be the best solution in this situation. Here are some references for creating and managing custom post types in wordpress:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-custom-post-types/

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types